# Wildcard doesn't work in Mingw (Windows) GNU ld script

Tags: gcc, cross-compiling, ld, binutils

I am using the tool chain provided by [GCC ARM Embedded](https://launchpad.net/gcc-arm-embedded). It seems ld (4.9-2015-q3-update) cannot handle wild card (*) with Windows path correctly.

For example, the code snippet below

```
.foo_v0 { obj\*(.s_foo_v0) }
```

won't find files under directory obj, and .foo_v0 gets nothing. Here is the report from mapfile:

```
.s_foo_v0       0x00008664       0x1c
 .s_foo_v0      0x00008664       0x1c obj\test\foo.o
                0x00008664                foo_v0

.foo_v0         0x00008680        0x0
 obj\test\*(.s_foo_v0)
                0x00008680                PROVIDE (__load_start_foo_v0, LOADADDR (.foo_v0))
                0x00008680                PROVIDE (__load_stop_foo_v0, (LOADADDR (.foo_v0) + SIZEOF (.foo_v0)))
```

Everything works fine on Cygwin, however, just need to use slash instead of backslash.

It's a known issue? Or is there a workaround?

Comment: Have you tried using a slash instead of a backslash even when you're not using the Cygwin environment?

Comment: It doesn't work either.

Comment: Perhaps try doubling the backslash to escape it: `.foo_v0 { obj\\*(.s_foo_v0) }`

Comment: doubling the backslash works. If I use only one backslash, it will escape the wildcard, so I need another backslash to escape the latter one?

Comment: Seems that way.  It's too bad it won't match using the forward slash.  Many GNU tools on Windows seem to be OK with using forward slashes as path separators. That would help with portability a little bit, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doubling the backslash solves the problem.

```
.foo_v0 { obj\\*(.s_foo_v0) }
```

Here is the report from mapfile,

```
.foo_v0         0x00008664       0x1c
 obj\\*(.s_foo_v0)
 .s_foo_v0      0x00008664       0x1c obj\test\foo.o
                0x00008664                foo_v0
                0x00008664                PROVIDE (__load_start_foo_v0, LOADADDR (.foo_v0))
                0x00008680                PROVIDE (__load_stop_foo_v0, (LOADADDR (.foo_v0) + SIZEOF (.foo_v0)))
```

It seems the first backslash escapes the latter one, so that the latter one won't escape the wildcard.